# ValueError in Python

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "filter_import.py", line 77, in <module>
        get(sys.argv[1])
    File "filter_import.py", line 35, in get
        timestamp, ip, hash_value = lines.split()
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

I got this error message when I run my code filter_import, can anyone explain a bit what the problem is?

Part of my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print 'Usage: filter_import.py <filename>'
    sys.exit(1)
get(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line in question doesn't provide two values, so the "unpacking" of `split()`'s return value into the two variables `timestamp`, `ip` and `hash_value` is failing.

Here's a stand-alone reproduction of the error:

```
>>> a,b,c = "foo".split()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: thanks, but what about this part? `File "filter_import.py", line 77, in <module>
get(sys.argv[1])`, is there anything wrong as well? @unwind

Comment: No. This a part of the stack trace. The stack trace shows you the lines of code the interpreter went through to get to the line of code raising the exception. In your example it just indicates that method `get` has been called from line 77 of your module.